# 2-cells in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

For the most part, `tikz-cd` seems like a nice replacement for `xymatrix`.  However, I miss the `2cell` option.  Is there a standard substitute, or do I have to roll my own?

For instance, here's something I write a lot using `xy` package:

```
\usepackage[all,2cell]{xy}
\UseAllTwocells
$\xymatrix{
  A \ar[r] \ar[d]
  \drtwocell\omit
  & B \ar[d] \\ C \ar[r] & D
}$
```

The best replacement I can think of so far with `tikz-cd` is rather more verbose:

```
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \ar[r] \ar[d]
  \ar[from=r,to=d,phantom,""{name=1,near start},""{name=2,near end}]
  \ar[Rightarrow,from=1,to=2]
  & B \ar[d] \\ C \ar[r] & D
\end{tikzcd}
```

Of course I could define my own macro that does this; I'm not looking for answers that essentially do that. I'm just surprised if `tikz-cd` has no feature like this available by default; is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: Since @gernot's answer perfectly solve this, do you have any other nontrivial example?

Comment: @Symbol1 what I was really hoping for is a *standard* way to make 2-cells in tikz-cd analogous to the xy 2cell package.

Answer (score 4):

Does this satisfy your expectations regarding succinctness?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{shorten <>/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
   A \ar[r] \ar[d] & B \ar[d]\ar[ld,shorten <>=10pt,Rightarrow]
\\ C \ar[r]        & D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, counting the `\tikzset`, it's not really much shorter than my version would be if I bothered to define a macro for it.  What I really wanted to know is if there's a *standard* way to do this, or whether whenever I write a paper with a coauthor we're going to find that each of us makes 2-cells in tikz-cd in different ways.

Comment: @MikeShulman The "standard" is probably the manual of `tikz-cd`, and there is nothing comparable to the two-cell feature of `xy`. Still, my solution for this particular case is still standard, since it is just an arrow from B to C (though a bit shorter). If you judge solutions by the number of characters, then replace `shorten <>` by its definition. For the 2-cell example in the xy manual, though, I don't think that there is a simple `tikz-cd` equivalent.

Comment: Of course, a 2-cell is *not* an arrow from B to C.  Drawing it as if it were an arrow from B to C makes it stretch to become much too long if the names of the objects are longer than single letters.  (This is also a problem with my solution.)

Answer (score 0):

You also can easily obtain this diagram with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

$ \begin{psmatrix} [rowsep=0.9cm, colsep=1.2cm]
A & B\\
C & D%
\ncline[linestyle=none]{2,1}{1,2}\ncput*[nrot=:U]{\Longleftarrow}
\psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15, nodesepA=4pt, nodesepB=2pt}
\ncline{1,1}{1,2}\ncline{1,1}{2,1}
\ncline{1,2}{2,2}\ncline{2,1}{2,2}
\end{psmatrix} $%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer to the question as stated, because it is not standard.  However, since gernot's answer mentioned another particular way to make 2-cells in tikz-cd, and I mentioned in a comment to that answer that it, like my suggestion in the question, has the problem of making the arrow stretch too much, I thought that for the sake of other readers I would post another way to make a 2-cell that doesn't stretch, and moreover has the advantage of being placed at the same position in the diagram that the xymatrix `twocell` command would be.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcounter{nodemaker}
\setcounter{nodemaker}{0}
\def\twocell#1{%
  \global\edef\mynodeone{twocell\arabic{nodemaker}}%
  \stepcounter{nodemaker}%
  \global\edef\mynodetwo{twocell\arabic{nodemaker}}%
  \stepcounter{nodemaker}%
  \ar[#1,phantom,shift left=3,""{name=\mynodeone}]%
  \ar[#1,phantom,shift right=3,""'{name=\mynodetwo}]%
  \ar[Rightarrow,from=\mynodeone,to=\mynodetwo]%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \ar[r] \ar[d] \twocell{dr} & B \ar[d] \\
  C \ar[r] & D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This corresponds to the `\omit` version of the xymatrix `\twocell` command, which I use much more than the non-`\omit` version.  If you want the curvy arrows too you can of course put them in with `\ar[#1,bend left] \ar[#1,bend right]`.